# NodeJS Fs readdir don't return extension of files

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

```
fs.readdir(uploads_folder, (err, files)=>{
    console.log(files);
});
```

Output:

```
[
  '306c630e6d9752a1fa60d2697a5c7921',
  '7ce2c14c986ae3234ae12ad5826dd97f',
  '9565e32910f30325e55fbc8e8a20182b',
  'd8259d5cd3a53d15fdaa5049ca827e84'
]
```

I would like to get it with extension.
Before writing this I've watched this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6jsAk-DDj2c and writting same code I don't get it anyway.
Thanks for help.

Comment: `fs.readdir()` does return filenames with extension.  So, if you're not getting extensions, then those files apparently don't have an extension.

Answer (score 2):

Then those are directories or files with no extension